# To put a comma in this sentence or no?

Tags: commas

She said, "I like dogs." He said, "I like cats."
I would like to combine these two sentences.

Do I put a period after dogs?
Is it

> She said, "I like dogs." and he said, "I like cats."

or

> She said, "I like dogs" and he said, "I like cats."

Comment: The second. And you're good to go.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: What if both sentences had an explanation mark?
She said, "I like dogs!" and he said, "I like cats!"